# Sublime theme modification - What class is this?

Tags: user-interface, themes, sublimetext2, sublimetext, color-scheme

What class is this within the Default.sublime-theme file?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is called "tab_control". Check [this forum post](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4648) for more settings to control tab layout.